# Alternative function of MAXIFS/MINIFS in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am in need of an alternative of `MAXIFS`/`MINIFS` function in Excel.

It is needed because I am not a Office 365 subscriber. As you know `MAXIFS`/`MINIFS` functions let you calculate under certain criteria, even the criteria that includes another cell/s. I can do a least amount of calculation using `MAX`/`MIN` and `IF` function, but the criteria/condition must be on the same cell/s. So it's my misfortune that can't come up on a solution to this case.

I want to use 2 conditions/criteria, so I couldn't use the `ARRAY` formula.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into `AGGREGATE()` as a LARGE or SMALL:

**MIN**:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$20/(($A$1:$A$20=D3)*($C$1:$C$20=E3)),1)
```

**MAX**:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$1:$B$20/(($A$1:$A$20=D3)*($C$1:$C$20=E3)),1)
```

[image]

---

You can also use the array form of  `MIN(IF())` and `MAX(IF())`

**MIN**:

```
=MIN(IF(($A$1:$A$20=D3)*($C$1:$C$20=E3),$B$1:$B$20))
```

**MAX**:

```
=MAX(IF(($A$1:$A$20=D3)*($C$1:$C$20=E3),$B$1:$B$20))
```

Being array formula they need to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but plz find a way to use 2 criteria, I tried with this array formula, but I cant. Now I am going to try AGGREGATE formula

Comment: for all you would just multiply the two together:  `(($A$1:$A$20="A")*($C$1:$C$20<>""))`

Comment: See edit  @Curiouslearner

Comment: @Curiouslearner I did add the second criteria.

Comment: see edit @Scott craner

Comment: You are missing the extra `()` around the denominator. @Curiouslearner

Comment: Yeah! I won't notice. Now this is solved